# Difference between `str.indexof` and `seq.indexof` in z3

Tags: z3

In the z3 [tutorial](https://rise4fun.com/z3/tutorialcontent/sequences), `str.indexof` and `seq.indexof` are mentioned separately. However, in the Z3 C API, there is only one relevant function, `Z3_mk_seq_index`. Does that function do special-case handling for the case of sequences of 8-bit BitVecs? Meaning, if my sequences are all strings, will `Z3_mk_seq_index` still use the `z3str3` codebase? Or will it fall back on z3's sequence solver?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no difference between a sequence of 8-bit values and a string in z3. In fact, all strings are treated as sequences of 8-bit values.

The only difference between `seq.indexof` and `str.indexof` is their type. The latter is simply a specialization of the former.

To switch between the regular string solver and z3str3, simply use the appropriate command line switch `smt.string_solver`. Valid options are `seq`, `z3str3`, and `auto`.

Comment: Thanks, exactly what I was looking for!